# Possible to change the order of the shortcut locations in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When you open a new Windows Explorer window by default it loads from the starting position "Computer" which shows your drives, etc.  This is all well and good except when Windows Explorer loads, it bumps the scroll bar down so that half the favorites are cut off.

I can scroll up to get to the ones I want, but that gets really old doing that 50 times a day. I do clean out my favorites frequently, but more are added all the time and used. In trying to come up with a fix for this problem I thought maybe it would be possible to move the link to "Computer" to be at the very top and the "Favorites" area directly under that, but I can't figure out a way to do that.  Anyone have an idea? Or maybe another solution I haven't thought of?

[image]

Comment: Here's an article on [How to Remove “Favorites” from Windows 7 Explorer Navigation Pane](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-favorites-from-windows-7-explorers-navigation-pane/). I believe [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) can also remove them.

Comment: I don't want it removed, I just want to move the location down below.  Ideally having Computer be at the very top then Libraries or Favorites next.